# How does one prove that $ C_{\mathbb P} (\mathbb{I_r})$ is closed where...

Tags: calculus, general-topology, continuity

How does one prove that $ C_{\mathbb P} (\mathbb{I_r})$ is closed where $$\mathbb{I_r}=[x_0-r,x_0+r]$$ and $$\mathbb{P}=\{(x,y): |y-y_0|\leq a, |x-x_0|\leq b\}\subset \mathbb G $$ where $\mathbb G-$ space of existence of a linear non-homogeneous differential equation and $ C_{\mathbb P} (\mathbb{I_r})-\text{set of continuous real functions on } \mathbb{I_r} \text{ whose graphs belong  to } \mathbb P.$ I honestly don't know what the complement to this set is, thereby don't know where to start from.

Comment: I don't see complement here.  To me $\overline{C}$ stands for the closure, does that mean complement to you?  What is the norm/topology for continuous functions you are working with?

Comment: If $A$ is a set , then $A^c$ is its complement.